# Sed: how do I replace all "#" characters with "%" (but in a batch file)

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, sed

I tried:

```
sed "s/#/\%/g"
```

but the batch file stripped out the %, and sed gave an error

```
sed "s/#/\x37/g"
```

didn't work either, it just put the text x37 in there

Note I need this to work in a batch file, not the command line.

Comment: Try `%%`, I believe `%` is an escape character.  Escape characters escaping themselves usually become a single literal.

Comment: excellent thanks that works!

Comment: @SteveBuzonas - The batch escape character is generally the `^`, but it does not work with `%`. The `%` is used for environment variable expansion, FOR variable definition and expansion, and argument expansion. A `%` literal must be escaped within a batch script as `%%`.

Answer (score 1):

`%%` does the trick:

```
echo "foo ## bar ##" | sed 's/#/%%/g'
```

Comment: just double check whether this works as you intend... single quotes and double quotes might give different results depending on shell you are using